# How does the lexical analyzer identify whether given token is Identifier or Keyword?

Tags: compiler-construction, lexical-analysis

I have a basic question on Lexical Analysis.
As lexical analyzer (which is a DFA which accepts lexemes and produces token) can produce tokens which can be Identifier([a-z]/[A-Z]/[0-9]  knowing digit not the first char), Keywords (if, else,..) , Operators & Delimiters.

So if a lexeme like 'whil' comes. Then will it be a lexical error stating **Its not a valid keyword** or **will it be accepted as Identifier**(variable), as lexical analyzer do not consider whether the syntax is right or not ?

Does Lexical Analyzer use different DFA for Identifiers, Keywords, Operators ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Then will it be a lexical error stating Its not a valid keyword

No.

> or will it be accepted as Identifier(variable)

Yes, and then there will be a syntax error from the parser.

> as lexical analyzer do not consider whether the syntax is right or not ?

The lexical analyser doesn't know anything about syntax. That's the parser's job.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Does Lexical Analyzer use different DFA's for Identifiers, keywords, Operators & Delimiters ?

Comment: I've never seen one that did, and I don't see any reason for it. *flex(1)* uses a single DFA.

Answer (score 0):

To identify keywords,
It uses the same regexp for identifier, and then checks the keyword table, whether it's a keyword. If yes, then keyword, else it is an identifier

Comment: Not necessarily. It is possible to write specific rules for the keywords.